# blender unknown error in cuLaunchKernel

Tags: rendering

My friend is trying to render an image but recently started getting the error

```
blender unknown error in cuLaunchKernel
```

after the ending of the error it seems to present some variables in a C function, this has only started happening recently. A couple of weeks ago the same scene was rendered fine and only started reworking on the scene today when it produced this error. Some information that might help

Windows 10 (64Bit)

GTX 1060 4Gb

Blender version 2.79

Comment: That's a CUDA error, make sure your drivers are up to date.  Also please note that this question is off-topic for this site.

Comment: Where would you say is a better place for this kind of question? Kinda put two and two together here seeing as it was being thrown in blender and only there.

Comment: Chances are it's a Windows 10 update that has borked your Cuda, make sure you have the latest drivers for you gfx card as these will likely be out of sync.  For things like this I would suggest https://superuser.com